# How to pin terraform provider?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm working on terraform rds cluster for building aurora , Can someone help me on how to pin the aws provider version to 2.0 ?

Is this a correct way to do it?

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"

  version = "<= 2.0"
}
```

Also my module earlier used 2.46 version, should i follow any steps while trying to do the downgrade?

Using terraform 0.12.6 version

Answer (score 6):

For anyone finding this on a search engine, the answer by Nathan was correct in 2020, but setting a version constraint in a provider block is now deprecated.

The new recommended method is to set `required_providers` in a global configuration `terraform` block.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "= 2.0"
    }
  }
}
```

If instead you want to pin to a major version and allow the minor version to increment, use the `~>` operator, which allows only the *rightmost* version specified to increment. E.g. `~> 3.0` allows upgrade for any version in the `3.x` space. More information can be found on the [Version Constraints](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/version-constraints) documentation.

See [official documentation](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/requirements) on provider requirements for more information.

Comment: Technically this is not an answer to the question, since the question itself is specifically about provider syntax from Terraform 0.12.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use just the equals operator `=` and not `<=`, which means "less than or equal to version 2.0".

If you want it to use version 2.0 only:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"

  version = "= 2.0"
}
```

See also https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/terraform.html#specifying-required-provider-versions

Comment: `version = "2.0"` will also express an exact match.